# How to migrate legacy eclipse rcp feature project from Mars(4.5) to Oxygen(4.7)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt, birt, eclipse-oxygen

I'am working on a RCP project which is currently running on Eclipse Mars(4.5) version. I need to migrate the project to oxygen version. But when i imported the project to workspace and run the application there were lot errors related to plugins. I tried Add-required option in .product file, but still many errors exists. Do any one have idea to how to correctly migrate the project to Oxygen version?

Below i have pasted one of the errors. I require cdt and birt plugin in project so have have already installed latest version of both. For cdt i tried old version also but that didn't work. 
Log:

```
!ENTRY com.contiautomotive.ertools.compare 4 0 2020-06-18 20:44:23.330
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.contiautomotive.ertools.compare [4]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.login
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.login; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
       com.contiautomotive.ertools.login [18]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.data
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.data; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
              com.contiautomotive.ertools.data [7]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.codegen
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.codegen; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                     com.contiautomotive.ertools.codegen [3]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                            com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm [2]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.main
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.main; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                                   com.contiautomotive.ertools.main [220]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.help.webapp
                                       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.help.webapp; bundle-version="3.9.1.v20170816-0843"; singleton:="true"
                                          org.eclipse.help.webapp [184]
                                            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.help.base; bundle-version="[4.0.0,5.0.0)"
                                              -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.help.base; bundle-version="4.2.153.v20180330-0640"; singleton:="true"
                                                 org.eclipse.help.base [182]
                                                   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.lucene.analyzers-common; bundle-version="[6.1.0,7.0.0)"
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.help.base
                                       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.help.base; bundle-version="4.2.153.v20180330-0640"; singleton:="true"
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.help.ui
                                       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.help.ui; bundle-version="4.1.0.v20170311-0931"; singleton:="true"
                                          org.eclipse.help.ui [183]
                                            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.help.base; bundle-version="[4.0.0,5.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                                              -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.help.base; bundle-version="4.2.153.v20180330-0640"; singleton:="true"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.main
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.main; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.continental.plm.codesizeparser
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.continental.plm.codesizeparser; bundle-version="1.2.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                     com.continental.plm.codesizeparser [40]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="6.4.0.201802261533"; singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.cdt.core [100]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.google.gson
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.main
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.main; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.migrateereleasezip
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.migrateereleasezip; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
              com.contiautomotive.ertools.migrateereleasezip [25]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.data
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.data; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.main
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.main; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.data
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.data; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.cm; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.contiautomotive.ertools.main
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.contiautomotive.ertools.main; bundle-version="6.35.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1613)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1528)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: Oxygen is still ancient (4 years and 10 releases old). You need to provide more details.

Comment: Why not migrate to the latest version, ie v4.16 (2020-06)?

Comment: I have added some log text. @greg-449 can you understand the problem there?

Comment: @titou10 we need a stable platform. I can try for latest version also, but if have any solution for this problem please provide it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work through the chains of unresolved requirements to see what the issue is. Check that the listed plug-ins are actually being included in the build. The list of plug-ins changes between releases.

In what you show one issue is `org.apache.lucene.analyzers-common`. This is new in Eclipse Oxygen so it looks like you need to update the list of plug-ins being included in the build.

If you are using a .product file use the 'Add Required' button to add any missing required plug-in. Note that using a feature based build rather than plug-in based deals with this much more easily.